# How to find out the number of CPUs using SNMP

Tags: linux, net-snmp

Is there a way to get the number of CPUs using SNMP in linux + net-snmp package (with the default net-snmp package mibs installed)?

[UC Davis SNMP mib](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/ucdavis.html) provides a lot of CPU information, but I do not see an object for the number of CPUs.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the implementation, but the HOST-RESOURCES-MIB hrDevice.hrDeviceTable should contain entries for the number of CPUs.

```
OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2
```

Any devices in the table matching:

```
hrDeviceType: .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.1.3
```

indicates a CPU/Core/HyperThread

There is also the HOST-RESOURCES::hrDevice.hrProcessorTable table, which should indicate their firmware ID's, which should help you differentiate cores/hyperthreads from physical cpus.